# C# Winforms Parent Child Instances

Tags: c#, winforms, parent-child, instance

In my application... to navigate between winforms what i do is that i make an object of the form that needs to be shown and i use

```
Register reg = new Register()
reg.show();
```

this thing has two problems

- if i do it with a button, more than
  one instance of same form could be
  opened.
- if i close through which the instance
  was created, the child form stays
  opend.

what is the solution....

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Take a look at [this](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/ParentChildWinForm/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=2039) code sample from MSDN code gallery. If you go through the code in detail, you should be good to go

Comment: the two probl;ems i have listed, the sample has the samp problem#1. And for problem#2 that seems to be solved in the sample. try making another child from a child its not solved. not helpfull buddy

Comment: If you are going to blindly follow it then there is no use. Downvoting me for this reason is simply rude, totally uncalled for

Answer (score 1):

have the child form take as a parameter the parent form:

```
Form2 f2 = new Form2(this);
this.hide();
f2.show();
```

then when you wish to close the new form you just close it and show the parent form again.

code from Form2:

```
private Form Fatherform;

Form2(Form father){
   Fatherform = father;
}

Form2_closeevent( ... )
{
    if(Fatherform != null)
       Fatherform.show();
```

Comment: no no man... the problem is that when i close the fatherform.. all the child forms should close...

Comment: ah, my bad. then you want Application.Exit();

Comment: no. no... i just wanted to close on child... hey i found the solution..
i am not going to create any instances in a button click event and on closing of that form i will close all the child forms.

Comment: thans for the answer "Form2_closeevent" got me to the solution